# Get HTML Canvas into Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, html5-canvas

I'm trying to get an HTML canvas into Google Spreadsheet.  I found a simple scribble pad which uses just html, css, and javascript.  I create a custom dialog and incorporate the scribble pad into it. That works fine.  Now I want to send to Google spread sheet.  What I have so far is:

In my HTML:

```
<canvas id="drawing-board"></canvas>
```

In my `<script>`:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('drawing-board');
var url = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
google.script.run.receiveDataURL(url);
```

In Code.gs:

```
function receiveDataURL(url) {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(url), 'image/jpg', 'MyImageName');
    sh.insertImage(blob,1,1);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

If I just insertImage(url,'image/jpg') I get a black box.  It should be white with some scribble on it.

Any ideas?

Comment: This topic has been resolved in this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71199292/how-to-get-html-canvas-from-custom-dialog-to-google-spreadsheet/71200394#71200394

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get HTML Canvas from Custom Dialog to Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71199292/how-to-get-html-canvas-from-custom-dialog-to-google-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 3):

As another answer, the method of "insertImage" can directly use the data URL. So your script can be modified as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function receiveDataURL(url) {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    sh.insertImage(url,1,1);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

- As a sample HTML&Javascript, you can test this using the following Javascript.

  ```
    <canvas id="drawing-board"></canvas>
    <script>
    const canvas = document.getElementById('drawing-board');
    canvas.width = 100;
    canvas.height = 50;

    // Sample rectangle image is put.
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(0, 0, 100, 50);
    context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    context.fill();

    // Retrieve the data URL.
    var url = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
    google.script.run.receiveDataURL(url);
    </script>
  ```

  - When this script is run, a red rectangle is put to "Sheet2".

#### Reference:

- [insertImage(url, column, row)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertImage(String,Integer,Integer))

Comment: I tried that but I got an image but it was a box filled black

Comment: @TheWizEd Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, when I tested this, a red rectangle is put to "Sheet2". So I cannot replicate your situation of `I tried that but I got an image but it was a box filled black`. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. But I would like to support you. So can you provide your whole script for correctly replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your current issue, I'm glad. Also, I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: If I do this `context.rect(0, 0, 100, 50); context.stroke();` in dialog I get a rectangle but in Spreadsheet I get a black filled box.

Comment: @TheWizEd This code works fine for me. Please post a new question including a [mcve].

Comment: @Ruben, with Tanaike's code you get a filled box not the outline of a rectangle.  I substitute `context.rect(0, 0, 100, 50); context.stroke();` which gives a rectangle in dialog but a filled box in Spreadsheet.  Which code works for you?

Comment: @TheWizEd Please post a new question including a [mcve].

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for your always support. When I tested my proposed script, again, a red rectangle is put to "Sheet2". Unfortunately, I cannot replicate TheWizEd's situation of `I tried that but I got an image but it was a box filled black`.

Comment: @TheWizEd From your comment to Rubén, I understood that my proposed script works in your environment. If my understanding is not correct, can you provide your whole script for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: It does not work see a new thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71199292/how-to-get-html-canvas-from-custom-dialog-to-google-spreadsheet

Comment: @TheWizEd Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the reason that you don't want to resolve your this question? If my proposed script doesn't work in your environment, I have to apologize. At that time, can you provide your whole script for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. I thought that when you use the complicated script, I had recommended testing it as a simple script. I deeply apologize for my proposal.

Comment: Please see the new thread.  Your answer does not resolve this problem.

Comment: @TheWizEd Thank you for replying. About `Please see the new thread. Your answer does not resolve this problem.`, I deeply apologize for my poor skill and my poor English skill. When I tested my proposed script, no issue occurs. This is due to my poor skill. When my proposed script didn't resolve your issue, can you provide the whole script for correctly replicating your issue? I had said this from my 1st reply. When you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it? I deeply apologize that I had wanted to resolve your this question.

Comment: Ruben asked me to start a new thread so please go here to continue the discussion thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71199292/how-to-get-html-canvas-from-custom-dialog-to-google-spreadsheet

Comment: @TheWizEd Thank you for replying. Can I confirm your direction? From your replying, you don't want to resolve your this question. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I do, but Ruben keeps telling me to open a new thread.  Your code does not work for me.  Please try this, change your code `context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";  context.fill();` to this `context.stroke();` and tell me if you get the correct image in Spreadsheet.

Comment: @TheWizEd Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot imagine your current script using my proposed script. Because when I tested my proposed script no issue occurs. About this, I have to apologize for my poor skill. But I would like to support you and resolve your this question. So can you provide your script for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. I'm continuing to say this from my 1st reply. I deeply apologize for this. By the way, if you cannot understand my English, please tell me.

Comment: @TheWizEd By the way, from `Ruben asked me to start a new thread so please go here to continue the discussion thanks stackoverflow.com/questions/71199292/… `, I proposed an answer for your new question. Could you please confirm it? If you want to still resolve your this question, I would like to support you. At that time, can you provide your script for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.