# How to get HTML Canvas from Custom Dialog to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, html5-canvas

I found a simple scribble pad which uses just `<canvas>` html, css, and javascript. I create a custom dialog and incorporate the scribble pad into it. That works fine. Now I want to send the image to Google spreadsheet. What I have so far is:

In my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Drawing app</title>
    <?!= include("CSS_Scribbler"); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="container">
        <div id="toolbar">
            <h1>Draw.</h1>
            <label for="stroke">Stroke</label>
            <input id="stroke" name='stroke' type="color">
            <label for="lineWidth">Line Width</label>
            <input id="lineWidth" name='lineWidth' type="number" value="5" min="1" max="10">
            <button id="clear">Clear</button>
            <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="drawing-board">
            <canvas id="drawing-board"></canvas>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?!= include("JS_Scribbler"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

In my `<script>`:

```html
<script>
  const canvas = document.getElementById('drawing-board');
  const toolbar = document.getElementById('toolbar');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  const canvasOffsetX = canvas.offsetLeft;
  const canvasOffsetY = canvas.offsetTop;

  canvas.width = window.innerWidth - canvasOffsetX;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight - canvasOffsetY;

  let isPainting = false;
  let lineWidth = 5;
  let startX;
  let startY;

  toolbar.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.id === 'clear') {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
    else if (e.target.id === 'submit') {
      try {
        var url = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
        google.script.run.receiveDataURL(url);
      }
      catch(err) {
        alert(err);
      }
    }
  });

  toolbar.addEventListener('change', e => {
    if(e.target.id === 'stroke') {
      ctx.strokeStyle = e.target.value;
    }

    if(e.target.id === 'lineWidth') {
      lineWidth = e.target.value;
    }
  });

  const draw = (e) => {
    if(!isPainting) {
      return;
    }

    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';

    ctx.lineTo(e.clientX - canvasOffsetX, e.clientY);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    isPainting = true;
    startX = e.clientX;
    startY = e.clientY;
  });

  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
    isPainting = false;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
  });

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
</script>
```

In Code.gs:

```
function receiveDataURL(url) {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    sh.insertImage(url,1,1);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

In my custom dialog this is what I see:

[image]

But this is what I get in Spreadsheet:

[image]

Comment: First, how about resolving [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71190111/7108653)? As your previous question, sending the data URL from Javascript side to Google Apps Script side was your goal. Using a simple sample script, I proposed an answer. I thought that first, how about confirming whether the data URL can be sent to Google Apps Script side and the data can be used with `insertImage`? If this was not the direction you expect, I have to apologize.

Comment: Ruben, the previous thead is not resolved.  I wanted to send the image to Spreadsheet but I did not get the correct image.  So I can not accept any of those answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the image is retrieved in JPEG format, the default color is black. When I saw your question, when you draw the line with the black color, the black rectangle is retrieved as the JPEG data. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. For example, if you want to confirm the script works, how about the following modification?

#### Pattern 1:

Change the line color from the black color to other and test it again.

#### Pattern 2:

Change the output mimeType. In this case, the background is the transpatent. So you can see the line with the black color.

##### From

```
var url = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
```

##### To:

```
var url = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
```

Comment: It turns out to be black on a black background.  If I change the scribble to another color in my dialog its that color with a white background.  But when I transfer to Spreadsheet it that color on a black backgourn.  (Sorry, I don't know how to include an inline image).
 How do I change the `url` background to white to match the scribble pad.

Comment: 'var url = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);' works.  Thanks

Comment: I have one more question for you.  With jpg the background is black, with png the background is transparent.  How do I get background white? css `backgrounc-color: white;` for canvas doesn't work.

Comment: @TheWizEd About your new question of `I have one more question for you. With jpg the background is black, with png the background is transparent. How do I get background white? css backgrounc-color: white; for canvas doesn't work.`, in that case, how about putting a white rectangle in the initial canvas?

Comment: Yes that works, I was hoping for an easier way , say css.